# Java script tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Below are more details about the issue:

When I copy paste from MS word normally it is working. But when I copy bullets and tables, formatting is disturbed. There are exceptions generated when copying. and font size / type is not reecognized. 
why is it happening?
What is the way out?
Is there a work around? 
Will this problem be solved if I upgrade to later version?

I tried various combincations of below mentioned properties, but it didnt work:

relative_urls: false,
  convert_urls: false,
  paste_convert_middot_lists: false;
  convert_fonts_to_spans: true,

plugins:"autofill,advimage,table,paste,spellchecker,searchreplace,print,fullscreen,visualchars,nonbreaking,inlinepopups,lists,advlist,olstartat",
paste_use_dialog : false,
paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
paste_convert_headers_to_strong : false,
paste_strip_class_attributes : "all",
paste_remove_spans : true,
paste_remove_styles : true,
paste_retain_style_properties : "",
fix_list_elements : true,
paste_text_sticky : true,
paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: true,
valid_elements :"[]",

Exception:

```
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="0" QFormat="true" Name="Normal"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 9"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
```

Comment: Tinymce version used: 3.5.11